# How to remove the last element from JQuery array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, element

I want to select some DOM elements into a clone object then I want to remove the last item. After trying it in Chrome console I see that clone's length does not decrease.

Example from Chrome console:

```
crumbs =  $("span",$("div[style='width:390px;background-color:white;'")[0]).clone();
```

jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[114]

```
crumbs.last().remove()
```

[​…​​]

```
crumbs.length
```

114

As you see, length is still 114 elements. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`crumbs.last().remove()` removes the last matched element from the DOM, it doesn't remove it from the jQuery object.

To remove an element from the jQuery object¹ use [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
var withoutLastOne = crumbs.slice(0, -1);
```

<sup>¹ Actually this will create a new object that matches one less element instead of modifying your existing object. You will usually not care about the distinction, but should be aware of it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To remove last element from the array you can use below code too.

```
var arr = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"];
arr.pop();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5Hd4/)

Comment: This does not work because I am operating on JQuery object, which is not a true JavaScript array. No pop() method.

Answer (score 0):

As people said, `.remove()` removes the element from the DOM. Another option than using `slice` on the final result is to use jquery's filtering before cloning the element:

```
crumbs =  $("span",$("div[style='width:390px;background-color:white;'")[0]).not(':last').clone();
```

Comment: Not a good idea in this case, because jQuery will need to actually test if each element matches the `:last` filter. This is not necessary because here we know from beforehand which elements match and which do not. Just something to keep in mind.